# only declaration of mod_deflate lost 400-600 ms on TTFB

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-deflate, page-speed

I would like to get to my site 100 score on google page speed and I only have the problem of TTFB in a few pages, a few pages in my TTFB is 400-600 ms.

Now I noticed a problem if I disable gzip compression, my site is under 200ms, and then passes the test of google page speed.

I have the problem of high TTFB with this configuration in my .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  # Compress HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Text, XML and fonts
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript

  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css

  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml

  # Remove browser bugs (only needed for really old browsers)
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
  BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
  Header append Vary User-Agent
</IfModule>
```

now, if erase this , my website not have the problem of TTFB but have the problem of gzip compression .

so what is the problem?, that if I enter only the declaration of the gzip compression I have TTFB high just the same.

why the only declaration of mod_deflate increase between 400-600 ms my TTFB ? it's normal ? why if not gzip never file increase equally the time?

with only this two line of declaration have the problem:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Loading extra modules do have an overhead, although I would not expect 400-600ms... mod_deflate.c works after the output has finished, maybe your application does not buffer its output ? (loading the module might force that ?)